# Unhandled exception Stack overflow win32 console application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stack-overflow

I have written a simulation code as a win32 console application using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express. The code works fine as long as three of my variables are under a certain length. They look like this at the beginning of my main.cpp and are only needed throughout this main.cpp file.

```
 #define Nx 19   
 #define Ny 19   
 #define Nz 19
```

I use these variables to create a few 3-d matrices within the main program

```
double a[Nx][Ny][Nz]; 

double b[Nx][Ny][Nz];
```

The code runs fine as long as `Nx`, `Ny`, and `Nz` are 18 or less, but when I try to use a larger number I get an error message that looks like: 
`Unhandled exception at 0x012dd4d7 in main.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.` The code then stops within `chkstlk.asm`. I am by no means an expert or even very experienced but if someone could explain how to get around this issue is fairly simple terms I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: well not counting the pointers that matrix takes 54872 bytes of stack space... the 32 bit stack on windows [may not be able to handle that by default](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/07/08/3261309.aspx)

Comment: Try to debug the programme and find the line at which it stops working. It seems that you are out of stack memory (whic is the space for statically allocated objects). This is of course limited but I doubt that your matrices that altogether take just several hundred kilobytes can exhaust the memory. There must be something else...

Comment: According to the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks.aspx) the default stack size is 1MB. Is this a recursive function?

Comment: It would be wise to post a minimal set of code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 arrays each of (assuming 2 byte double size) are 19 cubed times 8 bytes. For both that is in excess of 100 kilobytes. I am not certain how (or if) you do in windows it but you could increase your stack memory accordingly. Alternatively use dynamic allocation for your arrays. We can only imagine what else you have on the stack but if it is overflowing you need to increase the stack memory size or allocate memory on the heap.

Note that the difference in memory size for a 18x18x18 array and a 19x19x19 array is (53872 - 11664) = 42208 bytes for EACH of these arrays so the difference from changing 19 to 18 is not as insignificant as you might think

Comment: Looking back at what I was using these two arrays for, I don't think I need double precision, so I changed the arrays to float and it seems to work fine. Thank you for bringing the enormity of these matrices to my attention it really helped.

Answer (score 0):

Allocate the array in heap:

```
typedef int tdarray[Nx][Ny];

tdarray * a = new tdarray[Nz];

delete [] a;
```

Comment: Bah, bad idea. Major pain to get right. Putting it in a class would be the better solution, managing that with a smart pointer even better.